# Event Sourcing/CQRS Database constraints on Read Only Side

Tags: sql-server, database-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Our company would like to implement Event Sourcing/CQRS for our financial systems.

For the Read Only Model, should we apply Database constraints?
I know constraints should Not be on the Write event store side.
How about the Read only Model side?

Including:

- Unique Constraints
- Foreign Key Constraints
- Check Constraints
- Default Constraints
- Referential Integrity

Comment: An event is an accomplished, past-tense fact about reality. An event-sourced read model simply consumes events. What would your system's behavior be in the case that e.g. a unique constraint would fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the Read Only Model, should we apply Database constraints? I know constraints should Not be on the Write event store side. How about the Read only Model side?

That probably doesn't do anything useful.

Fundamentally, there are two cases.  One is that the constraints in the read model are not aligned with the constraints of the domain model.  If the domain model is the authority, then the read model is *wrong*.

The other is that the constraints are aligned, but the read model thinks the constraint has been violated because it has an incomplete view of what's going on.  IE, the domain model emitted events `[A,B,C,D]`, but the read model only sees `[A,B,C]` right now.

Now, the data in the read model should be understood to be stale; so it's not unreasonable to update the read model only when a new, consistent, view of the domain is available.

But even given that, it's still not clear if the constraint should be enforced by the data store, or by the event consumer that is populating the store.

I'm not sure the database constraints buy you anything during normal operations.

They *might* be a useful guide during exceptional operations; if somebody is trying to patch the read model "by hand", then having a redundant copy of the constraints in the database might protect against a data entry error.  (The usual recovery procedure for the read model is that you destroy the cached copy and rebuild it; but if that's going to take an appreciable amount of time, your SLO might be better served by repairing the existing copy until the new copy is available).

Answer (score 0):

I use db constraints on a read-model.

- FKs help with cascading deletes as well as telling you (if you get an exception) that you have some case in your app that ended up with an inconsistent state (maybe the app crashed at one point in the past and read model wasn't updated). A durable service bus alleviates that.
- Defaults are just default values, I don't see a problem.
- I use Unique constraints for idempotency purposes and ignore when violation happens .

You see, you can use db constraints for several purposes and none of them have anything to do with business constraints that you'd use in the write model.

Comment: I just learned read model should not be rejecting events from write store ever, this can read to asychronous behavior, rules should be enforced on Domain side, Example: Write store has child entry with no parent, this should flow into read model, as read-model should not be concealing data, hope this helps

Comment: Defaults should only add etl timedate and name of writer, defaults should not be adding business data, if write store has null business data, read store should have null business data, Write store is the truth of data